# Hello, why is it that the formula of Standard deviation (of both grouped and ungrouped data ) differs in different sources

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

For instance, the formula for standard deviation of UNGROUPED data in some books is $\sigma={\sqrt {\frac {\sum(x-{\bar X})^{2}}{n}}}$ while in some books, they subtract 1 from the n (number of items in the data set) i.e  $\sigma={\sqrt {\frac {\sum(x-{\bar X̄})^{2}}{n - 1}}}$
am a bit confused, what exactly is the major difference between the two

Comment: I went ahead and fixed it, but you have to surround your LaTeX with dollar signs ($) to have it be recognized.

Comment: The first formula is use for a population while the second for a sample. The difference between 'population' and 'sample' (even though they may refer to the same set of data) is how you treat them and what you wish to gain from them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calculating the standard deviation of a known discrete probability distribution (e.g., your $x$s are possible dice rolls), you divide by $n$.

If the distribution is unknown and you're trying to estimate the underlying standard deviation based on data you collected, you divide by $n-1$.

But if you have a lot of data -- so $n$ is very large -- the difference between $n$ and $n-1$ is negligible, so you might as well divide by $n$.